# Use C++ code in a C project

Tags: c, linux

I've a client that shipped a C++ code that I desesperately need to use in a **really big** project written in C.

The problem is: I can't rewrite that C++ code to be in C ... would be too easy, I don't have the IP on this code and the client has to maintain the code.

I also can't link my **really big** project in C using g++: this would break things!

I tried to turn the C++ code into a lib, exporting a C-Style interface (with extern "C", encapsulating classes into structures) but I have a problem while linking this lib to my project ... (remember, can't use g++ to link) : I end-up with undefined references to almost all of the STL
In despair, I statically linked the STL to the C/C++ wrapper lib I made but this didn't change anything.

I don't know much about C++ but I don't want to be writting a C++ STL/C wrapper for this particular use case.

right now, I've made a binary from the C++ code and I call it using fork/exec in my C code ... this is a really bad solution I'd like to avoid.

If anyone has a clue/direction/hint,
That would be much appreciated.

Thx,
Guillaume.

Comment: I don't understand the real problem; you have problem with compiling ? linking ? you don't want to link because of a restrictive license ?

Comment: You have to use a C++ linker if you mix C and C++.

Comment: I can do whatever I want with the provided C++ code ... except modify it. I'm free to link to it, make wrappers around it ... I can't use the C++ linker on my big C projects, I've lots of things in that C project that would break while using a C++ linker on it. I need a solution _without_ using a C++ linker... Also this is on Android, thepoosh removed the Android tag ... but anyway it's not relevant ... yet :)

Comment: You should explain why you cannot link using `g++` & `-lstdc++`, because that is the easiest solution....

Comment: plus vote from Azzy just to finish your century :)

Comment: @granquet can you offer at least 1 example of what can possibly break ? since you provide no-code and no practical example i think that the question it's still not that clear.

Comment: ie: I use function pointers all over the place, I have some dirty tricks with adresses of the goto labels... well, some things that will certainly break when changing the linker. just take it as a restriction: I can't use a C++ linker.

Comment: Your dirty tricks won't break the linker. You should try using `g++` for linking. (In all cases, the real linking is done by `ld`, but what and in what order things are linked is changing when using `g++` instead of `gcc` for linking; use `g++ -v` as linking command to find out).

Comment: @granquet, I am wondering did you ever sort this problem. What was your final solution? Can you provide details? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The real answer to this question, aside from Azzy's answer, is really a question of what you need to do to call your c++ code.

Using fork may be a good idea, but in general, I'd say that's not the right solution unless the C++ code takes some significant amount of time to execute in the first place [in which case the fork/exec overhead is small enough to not matter].

The right solution, in general, is to write a small interface between your program and the C++ code, using a C interface (and the `extern "C"` wrappers - don't forget to use `#ifdef __cplusplus` in the header that defines the interface, around the `extern "C"` so that you can use the same header file in both the C++ interface implementation and the calling C code).

Also beware of exceptions. You MUST NOT call C++ code that throws exceptions from C - they must be handled in C++, or BAD THINGS will happen (exactly what kind of bad things is not determinable - random code may be executed, or the system crashes, or some random erroneous output occurs, etc)

Answer (score 1):

You could link the shared C++ library with `g++` and link that with your program with `gcc`, something like:

```
 g++ -Wall -O -c -fPIC lib++/src1.cc -o lib++/src1.pic.o
 g++ -Wall -O -c -fPIC lib++/src2.cc -o lib++/src2.pic.o
 ## etc, compile each C++ file of the library
 ##
 ## then link the library with standard C++ library, etc...
 g++ -shared lib++/src*.pic.o -lstdc++ -o lib++/libpp.so
```

Then use that shared library in your C project:

```
 gcc -Wall -O -c src/file1.c -o src/file1.o
 gcc -Wall -O -c src/file2.c -o src/file2.o
 ## link your program with lib++/libpp.so
 gcc src/fil*.o -L lib++ libpp.so  -lotherlibs -o yourprog
```

Remember that you can link a shared library with other shared libraries.

<sup>Of course, you'll want to modify your building system, e.g. your `Makefile`-s, to do the above commands.</sup>

Remember also that some functions have the `constructor` [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) (and C++ compilation uses that a lot, for construction of static C++ instances). These functions are running before `main`; symmetrically, function with the `destructor` attribute are running after `main`. For dynamically loaded libraries loaded by `dlopen`, constructor functions are run during `dlopen` and destructor functions during `dlclose`.

<sup>As several others pointed out, beware of C++ exceptions thrown across a C boundary</sup>

Comment: You can compile C code with `-fexceptions`, this should make those C boundaries less obstructive when throwing exceptions.